# How to save Array of two or more json data's to sql using Spring data Jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa, microservices

I have 2 Tables in db One Header, Detail   , Detail Level stores the forgin key with entire object in it . Now my Question in here is the Header table contain's Primary id as "seqno"
for each seqno there can be multiple records in "Detail" Table. so how do i save array of Json data using spring data jpa

`The Proble is exactily in details pojo in there i tried for loop to save multiple data but it is saving only one data`

If i click on Save button in UI it will call this Method

```
   // Main Save or Update (Button) 

    @Override
    public void saveIndent(RilHdrsDTO dto) {
      RilHdrs rilHdr = new RilHdrs();
      RilDtls rilDtls  = new RilDtls();
      // RequesterUnits requesterUnit = new RequesterUnits();

      if(dto.headerNo() == null){
        updatedRilHdrs(rilHdr, dto);
        rilHdrJpa.save(rilHdr);
        updateRilDtls(rilHdr, rilDtls, dto);
      }else if(dto.headerNo() != null){
        RilHdrs rilHdrobj = rilHdrJpa.findById(dto.rilSeqNo()).get();
        }
        RilDtls rilDtlsobj = rilDtlsJpa.findByRilSeqnoAndDrugSeqno(dto.rilSeqNo(),dto.drugNondrugseqno());
        updatedRilHdrs(rilHdrobj, dto);
        updateRilDtls(rilHdr, rilDtlsobj, dto);
      }
    }
```

Header Table Pojo

```
   // Indent Information Dialouge Page

    private void updatedRilHdrs(RilHdrs rilHdr, RilHdrsDTO dto){

      Timestamp now = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
      if(dto.headerNo() == null){
        String headerNo = ModuleNo(INDENT_NUMBER_K);
        rilHdr.setHeaderNo(headerNo);
        System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
        System.out.println(headerNo);
        rilHdr.setCreatedDate(now); 
        rilHdr.setUpdatedDate(now);
      }

        rilHdr.setUpdatedDate(now);
      if(dto.reqUnitCode() != null){
        rilHdr.setRequesterUnitsByRqstrUnitCode(dto.reqUnitCode());
        RequesterUnits requesterUnitobj = requesterUnitJpa.findById(dto.reqUnitCode()).get();
        rilHdr.setRqstrCode(requesterUnitobj.getRqstrCode());
        rilHdr.setRqstrName(requesterUnitobj.getRqstrDesc());
        // rilHdr.setReqUnitGroupLevel(requesterUnitobj.get().getGroupSeqno());
      }
      if(dto.reqUnitCode() == null){
        throw new PhisException(ExceptionCode.NOT_FOUND, "reqUnitCode cant be null !");
      }

      if(dto.IssueUnitCode() != null){
        rilHdr.setRequesterUnitsByIssuerUnitCode(dto.IssueUnitCode());
        RequesterUnits issuerUnitobj = requesterUnitJpa.findById(dto.IssueUnitCode()).get();
        rilHdr.setIssuerCode(issuerUnitobj.getRqstrCode());
        rilHdr.setIssuerName(issuerUnitobj.getRqstrDesc());
        // rilHdr.setReqUnitGroupLevel(issuerUnitobj.get().getGroupSeqno());
      }

      if(dto.createdBy() !=null){
        rilHdr.setCreatedBy(dto.createdBy());
        rilHdr.setUpdatedBy(dto.createdBy());
        SecUser secUserObj = secUserJpa.findById(dto.createdBy()).get();
        rilHdr.setCreatedName(secUserObj.getFullName());
        if(dto.headerNo() !=null){
          rilHdr.setUpdatedName(secUserObj.getFullName());
        }
      }
      String itemGroup_rc_domain = "ITEM_GROUP";

      if(dto.itemGroup() != null){
        rilHdr.setItemGroup(dto.itemGroup());
        if(dto.itemGroup() == "D"){
          String rc_value = "D";
          RefCodes statusobj = refCodesJpa.findByRcDomainAndRcValue(itemGroup_rc_domain, rc_value);
          rilHdr.setItemDesc(statusobj.getRcDescription());
        }else if(dto.itemGroup() == "N"){
          String rc_value = "N";
          RefCodes statusobj = refCodesJpa.findByRcDomainAndRcValue(itemGroup_rc_domain, rc_value);
          rilHdr.setItemDesc(statusobj.getRcDescription());
        }
      }

      String indent_status_rc_domain = "INDENT_STATUS";
      if(dto.status() != null){
        // rilHdr.setStatus(dto.status());
        if(dto.status() == "open" || dto.status() == "Open" ){
          String rc_value = "Open";
          RefCodes statusobj = refCodesJpa.findByRcDomainAndRcValue(indent_status_rc_domain, rc_value);
          rilHdr.setStatusDesc(statusobj.getRcDescription());
        }else if(dto.status() == "Closed" || dto.status() == "Close" ){
          String rc_value = "Closed";
          RefCodes statusobj = refCodesJpa.findByRcDomainAndRcValue(indent_status_rc_domain, rc_value);
          rilHdr.setStatusDesc(statusobj.getRcDescription());
        }else if(dto.status() == "Cancelled" || dto.status() == "Cancel" ){
          String rc_value = "Cancel";
          RefCodes statusobj = refCodesJpa.findByRcDomainAndRcValue(indent_status_rc_domain, rc_value);
          rilHdr.setStatusDesc(statusobj.getRcDescription());
        }else if(dto.status() == "Fully Supplied" || dto.status() == "FS"){
          String rc_value = "FS";
          RefCodes statusobj = refCodesJpa.findByRcDomainAndRcValue(indent_status_rc_domain, rc_value);
          rilHdr.setStatusDesc(statusobj.getRcDescription());
        }else if(dto.status() == "Partially Supplied" || dto.status() == "PS"){
          String rc_value = "PS";
          RefCodes statusobj = refCodesJpa.findByRcDomainAndRcValue(indent_status_rc_domain, rc_value);
          rilHdr.setStatusDesc(statusobj.getRcDescription());
        }else if(dto.status() == "Rejected" || dto.status() == "Reject"){
          String rc_value = "Reject";
          RefCodes statusobj = refCodesJpa.findByRcDomainAndRcValue(indent_status_rc_domain, rc_value);
          rilHdr.setStatusDesc(statusobj.getRcDescription());
        }
      }

      String indent_approval_status_rc_domain = "INDENT_APPROVAL_STATUS";
      if(dto.apprStatus() != null){
        // rilHdr.setApproveStatus(dto.apprStatus());
        if(dto.apprStatus() == "Approved" || dto.apprStatus() == "Appr"){
          String rc_value = "Appr";
          RefCodes statusobj = refCodesJpa.findByRcDomainAndRcValue(indent_approval_status_rc_domain, rc_value);
          rilHdr.setApproveStatusDesc(statusobj.getRcDescription());
        }else if(dto.apprStatus() == "Cancelled" || dto.apprStatus() == "Cancel"){
          String rc_value = "Cancel";
          RefCodes statusobj = refCodesJpa.findByRcDomainAndRcValue(indent_approval_status_rc_domain, rc_value);
          rilHdr.setApproveStatusDesc(statusobj.getRcDescription());
        }else if(dto.apprStatus() == "Pending For Approval" || dto.apprStatus() == "PFA"){
          String rc_value = "PFA";
          RefCodes statusobj = refCodesJpa.findByRcDomainAndRcValue(indent_approval_status_rc_domain, rc_value);
          rilHdr.setApproveStatusDesc(statusobj.getRcDescription());
        }else if(dto.apprStatus() == "Rejected" || dto.apprStatus() == "Rej"){
          String rc_value = "Rej";
          RefCodes statusobj = refCodesJpa.findByRcDomainAndRcValue(indent_approval_status_rc_domain, rc_value);
          rilHdr.setApproveStatusDesc(statusobj.getRcDescription());
        }
        else if(dto.apprStatus() == "All" || dto.apprStatus() == "all"){
          String rc_value = "All";
          RefCodes statusobj = refCodesJpa.findByRcDomainAndRcValue(indent_approval_status_rc_domain, rc_value);
          rilHdr.setApproveStatusDesc(statusobj.getRcDescription());
        }else if(dto.apprStatus() == "Pending Issue Allocation" || dto.apprStatus() == "PIA" || dto.apprStatus() == "pia"){
          String rc_value = "PIA";
          RefCodes statusobj = refCodesJpa.findByRcDomainAndRcValue(indent_approval_status_rc_domain, rc_value);
          rilHdr.setApproveStatusDesc(statusobj.getRcDescription());
        }else if(dto.apprStatus() == "Pending Verify and Submit" || dto.apprStatus() == "PVS" || dto.apprStatus() == "pvs"){
          String rc_value = "PVS";
          RefCodes statusobj = refCodesJpa.findByRcDomainAndRcValue(indent_approval_status_rc_domain, rc_value);
          rilHdr.setApproveStatusDesc(statusobj.getRcDescription());
        }
      }

      if(dto.subGroup() !=null && dto.itemGroup() !=null ){
        rilHdr.setItemSubGroup(dto.subGroup());
        ItemSubgroups itemSubgroupObj = itemSubgroupsJpa.findById(dto.subGroup()).get();
        rilHdr.setSubgroupDesc(itemSubgroupObj.getSubgroupDesc());
      } 
      rilHdr.setRemarks(dto.remarks());
      rilHdr.setNoOfItems(dto.noOfItems());
      rilHdr.setNearExpFlag(dto.nearExpFlag());
      rilHdr.setNearExpDay(dto.nearExpDay() != null? dto.nearExpDay() : 0);
      rilHdr.setCatalogFlag(dto.itemCatalog());
      rilHdr.setStandardFlag(dto.standardFlag());
      rilHdr.setItemType(dto.itemType());
      rilHdr.setIssueType(dto.issueType());
      rilHdr.setIssueTo(dto.issueTo());
      rilHdr.setActiveFlag(dto.activeFlag());
      rilHdr.setApprovalRemark(dto.remarks());
      rilHdr.setTotalAmount(dto.totalamount()); 
    }
```

Detail Table pojo

```
   // Indent List Dialouge Page

    private void updateRilDtls(RilHdrs rilHdr, RilDtls rilDtlsobj, RilHdrsDTO dto){

      // for(int i = 0; i>=dto.rilDtlsDTO().size();i++){
      for(RilDtlsDTO rilDtlsdto : dto.rilDtlsDTO()){
        // RilDtlsDTO rilDtlsdto = dto.rilDtlsDTO().get(i);

        System.out.println("**************--------");
        System.out.println(rilDtlsdto);
        rilDtlsobj.setItemSeqNo(rilDtlsdto.itemSeqNo());

          rilDtlsobj.setRilSeqno(rilHdr.getRilSeqNo());
          if(dto.itemGroup().equals("D")){
          if(dto.itemGroup().equals(""))  throw new RuntimeException("itemGroup cant be empty cant be empty");
            rilDtlsobj.setDrugSeqno(dto.drugNondrugseqno());
          }else{
          if(dto.itemGroup().equals(""))  throw new RuntimeException("itemGroup cant be empty cant be empty");
            rilDtlsobj.setNonDrugSeqno(dto.drugNondrugseqno());
          }
          rilDtlsobj.setItemSeqNo(rilDtlsdto.itemSeqNo());
          rilDtlsobj.setRilSku(rilDtlsdto.Sku());
          rilDtlsobj.setMaxStorageQty(rilDtlsdto.maxStorage());
          rilDtlsobj.setAvgUsageQty(rilDtlsdto.useAgeAndIssueQuantity());
          rilDtlsobj.setGoodStkQty(rilDtlsdto.stockQuantity());
          if(rilDtlsdto.IndentQuantity().equals(0))  throw new RuntimeException("Indent Quantiyt cant be empty");
          rilDtlsobj.setRequestQty(rilDtlsdto.IndentQuantity());
          rilDtlsobj.setApproveQty(rilDtlsdto.ApprovedQuantity());
          rilDtlsobj.setParameter1(rilDtlsdto.backOrderQuanity());
          // rilDtlsobj.setAvgUnitPrice(rilDtlsdto.averageUnitPrice());
          // rilDtlsobj.setAmount(rilDtlsdto.amount());
          rilDtlsobj.setDrugStatus(rilDtlsdto.itemStatus());
          rilDtlsobj.setUrgentFlag(rilDtlsdto.urgentFlag());
          rilDtlsobj.setReject_Status_Flag(rilDtlsdto.rejectFlag());
          rilDtlsobj.setActiveFlag('A');
          rilDtlsobj.setCreatedBy(rilHdr.getCreatedBy());
          rilDtlsobj.setCreatedDate(rilHdr.getCreatedDate());
          rilDtlsobj.setUpdatedDate(rilHdr.getUpdatedDate());
          // rilDtlsobj.setAvgUnitPrice();
          Drugs drugobj = drugJpa.findById(dto.drugNondrugseqno()).get();
          if(dto.itemGroup() == "D"){
            rilDtlsobj.setDrugCode(drugobj.getDrugCode());
            rilDtlsobj.setDrugName(drugobj.getDrugName());
            RefCodes refCodesobj = refCodesJpa.findById(dto.drugNondrugseqno()).get();
            // rilDtlsobjobj.setDrugStatusDesc(refCodesobj.);
          }else if(dto.itemGroup() == "N"){
            rilDtlsobj.setNonDrugCode(drugobj.getDrugCode());
            rilDtlsobj.setNonDrugName(drugobj.getDrugName());
          }
          // Item itemobj = itemsJpa.findById(rilDtlsdto.itemSeqNo()).get();
          // rilDtlsobj.setItemCode(itemobj.getItemCode());
          // rilDtlsobj.setItemDesc(itemobj.getItemDesc());
          // rilDtlsobj.setItemType(itemobj.getItemType());
          // rilDtlsobj.setPreferedItemPackaging(itemobj.getPackaging());
          SecUser secUserObj = secUserJpa.findById(dto.createdBy()).get();
          rilDtlsobj.setUpdatedUsername(secUserObj.getFullName());
          rilDtlsJpa.save(rilDtlsobj);
      }

    }
```